# Access variable set in jQuery function from Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular

I have to do a workaround and initialize jQuery datetimepicker inside Angular 2 app  (and it should be reworked later).

When I assign datetime value to a variable, it is not visible anywhere else in Angular app. Here is what I do:

```
datetime: string;

setDT() {
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    onChangeDateTime: function(currentDateTime) {
      this.datetime = currentDateTime;
      console.log(this.datetime); // -> logs correct selected datetime, i.e. Fri Mar 11 2016 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
    }
  });
}
```

but if I try to reach out this.datetime somewhere else it is undefined:

```
save() {
  console.log(this.datetime); // -> 'undefined'
}
```

How should be variables passed between jQuery and Angular 2?

Roman

Comment: Somewhere else means what? in same component or in some other component?

Comment: I mean same component

Comment: can you reproduce in plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use jquery proxy to do that:

```
setDT() {
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    onChangeDateTime: jQuery.proxy(function(currentDateTime) {
      this.datetime = currentDateTime;
      console.log(this.datetime); // -> logs correct selected datetime, i.e. Fri Mar 11 2016 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
    }, this)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was able to get needed value through

```
this.datetime = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#datetimepicker").val();
```

but still would be great to receive an answer for educational reasons.

thanks again!